# How to create an online drawing application

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, flash

*I've tried to ask this question before, but I failed completely there. After useful input, I decided to leave that one, and to try again.*

I'm looking to create a web-based application where users can draw images built from a set of pre-defined icons. There is a need to be able to save the final image (encoded jpg/png), and also save a "current setup" that can be re-loaded later for further editing (a "settings" file?).

> **My question :** 
> What would be the best approach for this matter? Flash+AS3? HTML5+JS? Something else?

For better understanding of what I want to create, here are 2 screenshots that illustrate in what direction I'm thinking:

- The drawing application (made in Flash): [http://imgur.com/U4GNKJF](https://imgur.com/U4GNKJF)

[image]

- The final created picture: [http://imgur.com/aCtxwo1](https://imgur.com/aCtxwo1)

[image]

Thanks in advance, and I really hope I've made my question more clear this time.

Comment: I predict a `"Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or...` flaming on the Fayah haha... Anyways this actually has potential to be a good question. Ideally various tips from experienced coders covering all the angles. @BlackFayah, people here like these questions to be specific. The correct answer should help future visitors too but here, what really is the **_one correct answer_** to this?

Comment: @VC.One Haha, I was expecting that too. But if one answer helps me realizing what I want, it could be the answer for **me**, right?

Answer (score 1):

Since you need advice...

- Draw your icons in some art software (even online) and save as transparent PNG's
- Look-up **HTML5 Drag & drop** tutorials that involve "Canvas". You'll want to meaure the positions of objects dragged (mouse position on Canvas) and their order. The drag function could update a `JSON` String (this hold entries of items, type, position, etc)
- Look-up How to save JSON as text file, also **how to parse text file as JSON**. This becomes the "settings file".
- To save images best use PHP language code. PHP must be installed on the server (most have, or is installable or else get a better host). There are tutorials on how to save an image with content from **"snapshot of Canvas"**

Answer (score 0):

flash is unsupported on IOS and android mobile browsers and google is giving a lower index to websites using it.

I would use javascript with HTML5 canvas with PIXI.JS ,CreateJS or PANDA.JS.
These libraries make it easier to create the canvas elements you need (draggable objects, buttons ) from sprites and adding event listeners to them. 
And drawing graphics on the canvas (lines, shapes).

Since you have a lot of sprites you can pack them in a spritesheet with TexturePacker for faster loading ( and PIXI works great with spritesheets).

You can package this web page to android/ios with phonegap,ionic,crosswalk, cocoonjs etc ( i recommend ionic + crosswalk webview it gives great performance)

for saving i would also use a json file to save the setting . You can use PHP to load and save it.